# Http call angular is not waiting till the response is obtained

Tags: angularjs, http

In the below code , in the else if , the http call is made then the control is going to the next place(another controller). Is there a way i can make the http call complete then go to the then part where the reponse.data is achieved only then go to the next part of the code ? I can observe that after a few more steps , it will come to the reponse.data part but i want that to happen right after the call is made.

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    //var testEnv = envService.environment == 'development' || envService.environment == 'ci';
    testEnv = false;
    if(testEnv) {
        var user = _.find(self.getHardCodedUsers(), function(u) { return u.id == id; });
        if(user) {
            resolve(user);
        } else {
            reject('No user was found');
        }
    }
    else if($rootScope.plannerRedirect){
        var url = SessionService.jsonUrl();
        $http({
          url: url + '/user/plannerclient/profile/' + id,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.getToken()
          }
        }).then(
        function(response) {
            if(response.data) {
                resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                reject('No user was found');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            reject('Sorry, the query could not be performed.  Please check your network connection.');
        });
    }
    else {
        var url = SessionService.jsonUrl();
        $http({
          url: url + '/user/profile/' + id,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.getToken()
          }
        }).then(
        function(response) {
            if(response.data) {
                resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                reject('No user was found');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            reject('Sorry, the query could not be performed.  Please check your network connection.');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.success(function(){});` instead of `.then(function(){});`
You need a callback from server with a status code 2xx 200(ok), 201(Created), 202(Accepted).

Comment: I tried with .success. Still it is not going into the success part , it is following the same flow and then coming to the success after some time. Same like before. as per my debugging , it is coming to the http call step then going to the end of the function directly then doing to the next controller and after some more steps it is coming to the success.